# How do I create a JS file in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, file, save

I have a silly library that can only load the required meta data from another JS file. That file looks like this

```
// customStuff.js
__customStuff = [
 {.. stuff 1},
 {.. stuff 2},
 {.. etc}
]
```

That silly library uses a parameter called `custom_stuff_filename` which is a string that describes the custom stuff file

```
{
  custom_stuff_file_name: "customStuff.js"
}
```

`customStuff.js` sits in a public folder that looks like this `myapp/public/silly_library/static/customStuff.js` whereas the rest of my source code sits in `myapp/src/`

As you can see, `customStuff.js` is static. Stuff inside that file sits there only if I put it.

I don't want it this way. Instead, I want to make an API call in some file in my `src` so that a `__customStuff` is a result of that API call.

How do I do that? Is there any way in javascript where I can **save** data into another javascript file?

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way :-

```
componentDidMount{
    fetch("URL")
        .then(response => {
            response.blob().then(blob => {
                let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                let a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = '__customStuff.json';
                a.click();
            });
}
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery in my app